# Display .mbtiles on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, mbtiles

I have a .mbtiles and I want to display it on google map android sdk. I'm using **ExpandedMBTilesTileProvider** but the result is a blank page

```
TileProvider tileProvider = new ExpandedMBTilesTileProvider(new File("/sdcard/mydatabase.mbtiles"), 256, 256);
TileOverlay tileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(
     new TileOverlayOptions()
        .tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

Comment: did you check if your .mbtiles files is on the `/sdscard/` directory? I think you have to put in the path where your .mbtiles files is.

Comment: Thanks  for your response. Yes I checked the mbtiles and it's ok. But the map showing blank page!